# how to compute floats dynamically during runtime x86 assembler

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86

How do you work with single precision floats in x86 assembler during run time. i know you can use the .float assembler directive to include static floating point numbers during compile time, but how would you handle say a user entering a floating point number in base 10 and using it in your code.

ive done some reading over the last 2 days and converting the base 10 floats to and from the exponent and massisia make sense, but do i actually have to code a function to convert them back and forth to use them with floperators (floating point operators such as fadd, fdiv).

if so i guess i have to suck it up and create two functions to go back and forth from decimal to exponent massisia hex.

if not are there operations or instructions that do this for me? if so what are they or if you could link me to a document page on them.

thanks for your time and hopefully this post made sense.

Comment: Is it okay to use runtime library conversion functions like `gcvt()` and `atof()`?

Comment: me and a friend have been researching this to do it our self and avoid others functions. they will most likely be used in our end application when we make it but we are trying to learn how to do this our self before using others functions... for the sake of learning

Comment: @randynewfield I am all in favor of learning by doing - I just finished writing a linked list merge sort for programming language practice. However, I'm not sure decimal<->binary float is a good choice of exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Many C compilers, including gcc, have an option to generate assembly language. Although not easy, it is much less difficult to code this sort of thing in C and use a compiler to get assembly language that you can then adjust to your needs.

Watch out for denormalized numbers and signed zeros. They may need special handling.

You can study the methods involved at least well in C as in assembly language. In assembly language, it is hard to see the big picture because of all the messy detail. I would not try to write something like this directly in assembly language unless you have absolutely no other choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the user input - then the answer is clear. The user **can't** input floating point numbers. The user always input **strings**. (Or even more exact - the user always input key strokes, but anyway any decent OS will convert these to string for you)

So, you always must convert strings to numbers - integer, float or any other format.

Most of the high level languages make this conversion calls transparent, but in assembly language you have to make them explicitly.

It is another talk what conversion functions you to use. It depends on your goals and running environment. You can write these functions yourself. Or to use these provided by standard C or any other language functions. Or use OS provided libraries.